# Phase spectrum with python and FFT

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to calculate a phase spectrum of sinusoid.
The following code generates 1Hz sinusoid with zero initial phase.

```
import numpy
from numpy import pi, sin, arange
from pylab import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel, xlim, grid

sampling_rate = 500
sampling_time = 1 / sampling_rate
length = 1 # in seconds
n = sampling_rate * length # number of points

time = arange(0, n * sampling_time, sampling_time)
# Generate sinusoid: frequency=1Hz, phase=0
signal = sin(2 * pi * time)

fft = numpy.fft.fft(signal)
fft_phase = numpy.angle(fft)
fft_freq = numpy.arange(n) * sampling_rate / n

plot(fft_freq, fft_phase)
ylabel("FFT Angle")
xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
xlim(left=0, right=5)
grid(True)
show()
```

But result doesn't match my expectations. It has non-zero phase of 1 Hz component:

[image]

It shows incorrect phase of 1 Hz harmonic. What's wrong with the code (or approach)?

Answer (score 1):

When the magnitude is zero, then the phase is given by numerical imprecision.

If you display the values computed by `fft` you’ll see that the values you expect to be 0 are actually in the order of 1e-16 or something like that. This is numerical imprecision caused by rounding in the floating-point computations.

The solution is to compute both the magnitude and the phase, and ignore the phase component if the magnitude is too small.

Comment: Magnitude of 1 Hz component is not a zero. I agreed with everything else you wrote. But it doesn't explain incorrect phase of 1 Hz component.

Comment: @tmporaries: seems to be -pi/2, as expected. The cosine has a phase of 0.